# After detecting collision between my character and an object, the character is no longer able to move?

Tags: c, sdl, game-physics, sdl-2

I'm creating a game where you can move a dot along the x axis in the middle of the screen and there will be elements falling from the top that you will need to try and dodge, clearly for this I need some form of collision detection, which I have implemented and it appears to work correctly.

My problem is that when the character (dot) has moved towards the object and the collision has occurred, you are no longer able to move the character, it simply stays in a fixed position. This does not happen when the character collides with the edges of the window, however as you will see below both the window collision and object collision have the same code to run.

Main game loop:

```
  while(running) {

    // Queue of the events happening
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        running = false;
      }
      else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.repeat == 0) {
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
          case SDLK_UP:
            //sprite->yVel -= VELOCITY;
            break;
          case SDLK_DOWN:
            //sprite->yVel += VELOCITY;
            break;
          case SDLK_LEFT:
            sprite->xVel -= VELOCITY;
            break;
          case SDLK_RIGHT:
            sprite->xVel += VELOCITY;
            break;
        }
     }
     else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.repeat == 0) {
       switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
         case SDLK_UP:
           //sprite->yVel += VELOCITY;
           break;
         case SDLK_DOWN:
           //sprite->yVel -= VELOCITY;
           break;
         case SDLK_LEFT:
           sprite->xVel += VELOCITY;
           break;
         case SDLK_RIGHT:
           sprite->xVel -= VELOCITY;
           break;
       }
     }
   } // Poll event loop

   float timeStep = getTicks(ticks) / (float) 1000;
   move(sprite, timeStep, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, head);

   startTimer(ticks);

   // Clear window then draw image
   SDL_RenderClear(rend);
   SDL_RenderCopy(rend, background->element, NULL, NULL);
   SDL_RenderCopy(rend, sofa->element, NULL, &sofa->dest);

   setPosition(sprite, sprite->xPos, sprite->yPos);
   SDL_RenderCopy(rend, sprite->element, NULL, &sprite->dest);

   SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
   capFrameRate(timeStep);
} // Main game loop
```

Move and Collision functions:

```
void move(Character *c, float timeStep, const int WIDTH, const int HEIGHT, Scene *scene) {
  c->xPos += c->xVel * timeStep;

  // Collision check for the walls
  if(((c->xPos < 0) || (c->xPos + c->dest.w > WIDTH)) || (collision(c, scene))) {
    c->xPos -= c->xVel * timeStep;
  }
}

bool collision(Character *character, Scene *scene) {
  if(SDL_HasIntersection(&character->dest, &scene->element->dest)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    if(scene->nextElement == NULL) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      collision(character, scene->nextElement);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

As there will be a few elements falling from the top of the screen I've implemented a Linked list for those, hence why the recursion on the collision function. If anyone has any idea on why the character does not move after collision I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: your `collision(c, scene)` method looks at collisions *for the current time step*. In that case, your if statement in the `move` function

```
                                                      //  \/ This here is the problem -- if you're currently colliding with an object you don't allow any movement, even if you're moving out of the object  
if(((c->xPos < 0) || (c->xPos + c->dest.w > WIDTH)) || (collision(c, scene))) {
    c->xPos -= c->xVel * timeStep;
}
```

the player is not allowed to move after she has collided with an object. The solution is to check for collision *before* you take the step:

```
float newX = c->xPos + c->xVel*timeStep;
float newY = ...;
if (!collision(newX, newY, scene)) {
    c->xPos = newX;
    ...
}
```

Comment: So do you mean I should initiate the move function before the event queue?

Comment: @JLW I am not sure what that means. My suggestion is to _check and see if your next position is an allowed position_, not to check if your current position is allowed or not. If you have moving collision bodies, you'll have to do some extra modifications however.

Comment: Ah ok yes I get what you mean now. I'll give that a go in a day or two, thanks for the help, will let you know if it solved things! Thanks!